# How to hide long text in responsive div?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with this design. I want to hide the excess text that the div can't contain. I've tried using "***overflow: hidden***" and "***word-wrap: break-word***" but both don't work. Here's the html and css.

```css
.contents {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.instagram {
  background-image: url("https://snd-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/flat/instagram.png");
}

.logos.logos-lg {
  background-size: 120px auto;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.logos {
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  background-position: 1px 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.box_panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 132px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.box_icon {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.box_icon .logos {
  margin: 5px auto !important;
}

.box_body {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.box_body h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
  <div class="box_panel">
    <div class="box_icon">
      <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_body">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
  <div class="box_panel">
    <div class="box_icon">
      <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_body">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
  <div class="box_panel">
    <div class="box_icon">
      <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_body">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
  <div class="box_panel">
    <div class="box_icon">
      <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_body">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I try to resize the page, specially to the smallest screen size, the text just bleeds out of the div which is not very pretty. I can't set the of the **box_body** because it's supposed to follow the size of the **col-***.

Comment: Have you tried using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in the selector you want to control the text? [More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow), [text-overflow Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow)

Comment: Tried that one too. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.box_body`. And to create some "padding" there so that the overflow point isn't up against the edge of the parent, limit that element's `height` with `max-height: calc(100% - 15px);`

```css
.contents {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.instagram {
  background-image: url("https://snd-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/flat/instagram.png");
}

.logos.logos-lg {
  background-size: 120px auto;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.logos {
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  background-position: 1px 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.box_panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 132px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.box_icon {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.box_icon .logos {
  margin: 5px auto !important;
}

.box_body {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: calc(100% - 15px);
}

.box_body h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This saved me. Thanks a lot bro!

Comment: Also can we do something about the parts of the text that is showing near the border? It looks like it's hidden but not entirely hidden. Can I do a margin or padding here?

Comment: @Paul sure, edited my answer and moved `overflow` to `.box_body` and also gave that element a max-height of `calc(100% - 15px)` where `15px` is the space at the bottom.

Comment: you sir, are a life saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found why your code doesn't work. You are putting the attribute in a wrong css class. I made a modification to your css code and now it works.

Regards.

```css
.contents{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
.instagram {
    background-image: url("https://snd-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/flat/instagram.png");
}
.logos.logos-lg{
    background-size: 120px auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
.logos{
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    background-position: 1px 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
.box_panel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 132px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box_icon{
    float: left;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.box_icon .logos{
    margin: 5px auto !important;
}
.box_body{
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    
}
.box_body h4{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live. Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
             Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live. Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
             Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live. Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 contents">
    <div class="box_panel">
        <div class="box_icon">
            <div class="logos logos-lg instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_body">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
             Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live. Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
            Some Text long text description goes here in the body of the panel box, just a filler for the real content that will stay here once this goes to live.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! the same answer as Michaels' above, but I had to give him the accept since he answered first. Thank you so much though!

Comment: No problem Paul, I write english slower (joke). I´m glad that you recieve an answer usefull for you. Regards

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael mentioned you need to change `overflow-y` on `.box_panel` to eaither `hidden` or `auto`(if you want to allow scrolling). The problem is that `overflow` has initial value `visible` -- ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to fix the length of text.

wrap text after h4 tag in p tag or any other tag

```
$(".box_body p").text(function(i, t) {
    return (t.length >= 70) ? t.substring(0, 70) + '..' : t;
  });
```

Comment: that would work. but a simple css manipulation would be better.